# R XLConnect Set text alignment

Tags: r, xlconnect

I use XLConnect package to create Excel table from R.

Is it possible to set alignment of the content of some cell with XLConnect or with some compatible tool? In particular, I would like to center text inside table cell.

Thank you in advance,
Natalia

Comment: I found this today while looking for the same answer. Are you using some sort of a template, or are you creating the Excel file from scratch? From what I can find, there's no DIRECT way to do this, but I found a work-around if you are using a template Excel file.

Comment: I create an Excel file from R (through `loadWorkbook(out_file, create = TRUE)`, `createSheet`, `createCellStyle` etc.), without template.